# Bind one property to another and chain/fire OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I'm binding to properties from XAML in a WPF application, but this query is about raising 'PropertyChanged' events on one class property when another is raised in a different class/object. One use case is where a combobox ItemsSource binds to a property (PropB in my simplified example below) and that property returns a collection based on other properties (PropA below). PropB in class B needs to raise PropertyChanged when PropA in class A changes, but class A does not reference class B.

Is there an existing method or framework to have a property of an INotifyPropertyChanged object raise 'OnPropertyChanged' when a property in another object changes?

Below is an example of what I'd like to do using a made-up "Notify" property attribute as a binding path:

```
public class A : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string m_PropA;
    public string PropA
    {
        get { return m_PropA; }
        set
        {
            if (m_PropA != value)
            {
                m_PropA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PropA");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public A ARef { get; private set; }

    string m_PropB;
    [Notify("ARef.PropA")]
    public string PropB
    {
        get { return ARef.PropA; }
    }
}
```

Ideally the attribute would create a binding to each property in the property path (ARef and PropA) and when either of them changed it would call OnPropertyChanged on class B passing in "PropB" as the propertyName argument. I'm assuming that the ARef property also needs to raise an event when changed, but it'd be nice if it didn't.

I'm guessing this would require a bit of reflection and weak event listeners. Hopefully something exists that I can use. Apologies if this has been answered before.

Comment: If there is something like a "ViewModelA" and a "ViewModelB", you can use the `Mediator` pattern to send messages from one to another. There are a few articles on that topic in the web, like this one: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit short on time so I'll ask before reading further - does that require A to send messages to B when B is referencing A? In my example above, A could be in an assembly referenced by a different assembly containing B, and therefore A cannot send messages to B (ie it is not aware of B). Hope that question makes sense.

Comment: `Mediator` is all about objects sending messages "to whom it may concern", communicating objects would not need to "know" each other, no reference from "A" to "B" required or vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

Tip1 (Binding)

- change your binding from Path=PropB to Path=ARef.PropA and add OnPropertyChanged into ARef setter in class B.
- in this case value will be changed when you change ARef property in class B or PropA in class A

Tip2 (Event Chain)

- In setter of A (in B) add event handler to PropertyChanged event of class A. n handler, Raise PropertyChangedEvent of PropB when arg contains PropA.
- *Manual Event Fire is a good way to forget something, and turn your application chaotic*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tip1 won't work in my real world cases because PropB may derive a value based on multiple other properties rather than just directly returning the value of ARef.PropA. Tip2 sounds like a manual version of an event chain which I'd rather do in a cleaner and safer way with weak events.

Comment: If PropB is based on multiple other properties - and they have PropertyChangedEvent - you could use Multibinding and MultiValueConverter.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said 'derived from'. PropB generates a value based on the state of other properties. For example, PropB might return a list of database table names and PropA might be part of some database connection details like a server. Anything bound to PropB needs to requery when PropA or RefA change (including other objects in the Model using PropertyChanged events when running without a UI).